# Android not properly displaying > on TextView

Tags: android, xml

I've tried searching for it, but I can't seem to find anything, since searching with either > or &gt; doesn't really give you the intended search result.

The problem I'm facing is, that whenever I put a string into strings.xml, for example I typed in,

1 > 2 > 3

It changes it to 1 &gt; 2 &gt; 3

I've tried hardcoding the string in the layout file itself, but it seems to automatically change to &gt;, and I've tried running it on the emulator, as well as it showing on the preview, it seems to only show the html number of it.

Any solution would be appreciated. Of course, I would like to avoid typing all of the text manually by using `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: I think your question is unclear. What do you really want to do. > is a special character in XML (as & and <), and it's supposed to be replaced by &gt; in XML (thus layout) files. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: @Orabîg It doesn't show the >. It doesn't appear that way when I run it on the emulator. It shows the html code instead of >. As in the text displayed is the HTML code instead of >

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, because I've made a test project, and it's working as intended :

in my res/values/string.xml file :

```
  <string name="test_string">This is &gt; a string &lt;</string>
```

in my res/layout/main.xml file :

```
 <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_string" />
```

And on my Android device, it's showing :

**This is > a string <**

Can you post an extract of your own string.xml and layout file, and give a screenshot of your app ?